# firebase changePassword doesn't throw error for incorrect old password

Tags: ios, passwords, firebase, firebase-security

Our app uses Firebase simple login. It appears to work great, including most of the extra calls they include like resetPassword.

changePasswordForEmail also appeared to work. It correctly reset the password when the user would give it the correct old password and a new password. But when you give it the wrong old password, it doesn't throw an error. I printed out the success and error when giving it a wrong old password:

> > Success is: 1
> >
> > Error is: (null)

Code inside our user client:

```
[AuthClient changePasswordForEmail:email oldPw:oPw newPw:nPw completionBlock:^(NSError *error, BOOL success) {
    NSLog(@" Success is: %hhd",success);
    NSLog(@" Error is: %@",error);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationNameOnMainThread:kNotificationUserUpdateAccountInfo object:self userInfo:@{@"error":error?error:[NSNull null]}];
    if (error) {
        [UIAlertView showAlertWithError:error];
        return;
    }
```

And inside our authClient

```
+ (void)changePasswordForEmail:(NSString *)email oldPw:(NSString *)oPw newPw:(NSString *)nPw completionBlock:(ClientCallbackSuccess)block
{
    FirebaseSimpleLogin *authClient = [[FirebaseSimpleLogin alloc] initWithRef:[ClientBase shared].root];
    [authClient changePasswordForEmail:email oldPassword:oPw newPassword:nPw completionBlock:^(NSError *error, BOOL success) {
        if (block)
            block(error, success);
    }];
}
```

It would surprise me if this wasn't caught yet if it was in fact a problem with the api. I'm probably just doing something hair brained. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] I'm looking into this, and should have an answer / solution within the next few days.

Comment: Has there been any resolution for this? I am finding the same problem, the passwords are reseting fine and the code all seems to be working it is just that the SUCCESS bool always comes back as 1 meaning we can't alert users when they have entered the wrong previous password

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug impacting the iOS and Android client libraries for Firebase Simple Login, which has been fixed in the latest versions ([Simple Login iOS v1.3.3](https://cdn.firebase.com/ios/FirebaseSimpleLogin.framework-1.3.3.zip) and [Simple Login Android v1.4.1](https://cdn.firebase.com/java/firebase-simple-login-1.4.1.jar)).

Also note that the Firebase Simple Login clients are open-source. Check out https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login for the Web client and links to the Android and iOS clients. If you encounter bugs, don't hesitate to file them!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue using the firebase sdk for Android. The authentication via Simple Login works fine but changePassword always returns the error value null. But the API seems to work correct, because there appears an error message on the ADB output console.

Server Response on ADB console

```
    {
    "error": {
     "message": "The specified password is incorrect.",
     "code": "INVALID_PASSWORD"
     }
    }
```

Response from changePassword

```
Error = null, success = 1
```

I'va already looked into the implementation of the api at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/firebase/simplelogin/SimpleLogin.java but can't find any bugs.